# Page break (new page) in plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

While diverting output of the plot to a PDF (or other) file, how to make page break, such that the new plot is forced to be drawn on a new page?

Using normal `plot()` or `ggplot()` functions automatically draws new plot on a new page. However 
I am using package `VennDiagram` to draw some Venn charts. The problem is that when I try to make several diagrams, all of them are plotted on the same page:

```
library("VennDiagram")
pdf("foo.pdf")
draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = 100, area2 = 100, cross.area = 20, 
    category = c("A", "B"), fill = c("blue", "red"), lty = "blank")

draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = 200, area2 = 200, cross.area = 100,
    category = c("C", "D"), fill = c("blue", "red"), lty = "blank")
dev.off()
```

Here is the result, while I want to separate plots on different pages:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can force a new page using `grid.newpage()`

```
pdf("foo.pdf")
draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = 100, area2 = 100, cross.area = 20, 
    category = c("A", "B"), fill = c("blue", "red"), lty = "blank")
grid::grid.newpage()
draw.pairwise.venn(area1 = 200, area2 = 200, cross.area = 100,
    category = c("C", "D"), fill = c("blue", "red"), lty = "blank", add=FALSE)
dev.off()
```

Essentially, `VennDiagram` uses grid graphics to handle the drawing aspect. So, we just force a new graph to be created using `grid.newpage()`.

Comment: What package does `grid.newpage()` come from? I don't have it.

Comment: The grid package